# copying user profile on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, user-profile, user-accounts

Is there a tool or a trick to easily duplicate a windows profile?

My problem is that I have a local user profile and I like to copy that for another user.

Additionaly that profile was created locally when a domain-user logged in, and I like to create a copy of that profile for a non-domain-user.

Hope it's clear what my problem is.
Thank you for reading!

I've just seen there is a similar question:  [Copy Windows 7 profile from one domain user to another](https://serverfault.com/questions/158952/copy-windows-7-profile-from-one-domain-user-to-another)

Now I like to know if it is possible to simply change the user-profile's Name and Password.
Is this somehow possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy Windows 7 profile from one domain user to another](http://serverfault.com/questions/158952/copy-windows-7-profile-from-one-domain-user-to-another)

Comment: Note that I ask for a way to simply change the credentials of the user-profile, instead of copying it!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience Windows 7 does not allow you to copy and rename a profile. Attempting to do so will result in users with the same username as that on the profile being unable to create a proper profile when on the computer(instead they will receive an error stating that they can only log on to a temporary profile).

Depending on how many users you need to duplicate this profile for, you may find that booting into Audit mode and applying your profile specific settings, sysprepping the machine and then creating an image from that machine will be your best bet to have a standard or 'default' profile across multiple users. That may be beyond what you are trying to do here though.

Comment: thank you. But unfortunately no what I was looking for. I not need a default profile. I want to change the profile in a way that it gets independent from the AD. son instead of logging in to the AD with myDomain\myUser, I wanted to be able to log in to the profile localy like myComputer\myUser.